# ajax weird bahavior in url after deleting data in browsers cache

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, web-services

I have a C# Webservice which I'm contacting through URL to retrieve data. The Webservice is lying on a local server in our company network. For example: I have a specific function to get street names, the url to webservice is like this :

Request URL:`http://10.1.1.32:8080/webportale_ger_webservice.asmx/SelectStreets`
This URL is stored in localStorage.

After deleting browsers cache the request URL  has changed, which makes absolutly no sense to me:

```
http://10.1.1.32:8081/nullSelectStreets
```

The port is wrong and what about that null?

After trying this request several times again, the url value changes to the correct value.

My jQuery ajax Request looks like this:

```
 var UrlToWebservice = window.localStorage.getItem("url_to_webservice");

   $(document).on("keyup", "#input_strasse", function () {

            var inputStr = $('#input_strasse').val();
            var charStr = inputStr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + inputStr.substr(1);


            console.log("buchstabensuppe: ", charStr)

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',
                url: UrlToWebservice + 'SelectStreets',
                data: { 'charStr': charStr },
                crossDomain: true,
                dataType: 'xml',
                success: function (response) {


                    $("input_strasse_datalist").empty();
                    var strassen = new Array;


                    $(response).find('STRASSE').each(function () {


                        var strasse = $(this).find('NAME').text();

                        var plz = $(this).find('PLZ').find('plz').text();

                        var ort = $(this).find('PLZ').find('ORT').text();

                        var arstrasse = $(this).find('AR').first().text();
                        console.log("arstrasse ", arstrasse)

                        $("#input_strasse_datalist").append('<option data-ar = ' + arstrasse + ' value = "' + strasse + ' (' + plz + ', ' + ort + ')">' + strasse + ' (' + plz + ', ' + ort + ')</option>')

                        $("#input_plz").val(plz)
                        $("#input_ort").val(ort)
                    })

                },

                error: function () {
                    window.location.hash = "httperror";
                }
            })



        })
```

The value in localStorage is: http://10.1.1.32:8080/webportale_ger_webservice.asmx/

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You didn't show what UrlToWebservice is.

Comment: sorry, i get UrlToWebservice like this: 
var UrlToWebservice = window.localStorage.getItem("url_to_webservice"); It's a global variable...but now i use it local. seems to work.

Comment: And what is url you are calling this from? I mean url of current page while this is being executed.

Comment: the clients url is http://10.1.1.32:8081/#sp_anmelden

Comment: So that is why. After you clear browser cache, your url from local storage is gone. `UrlToWebservice` is null and you post to null + "SelectStreets", so to "nullSelectStreets". Because it's not absolute url, request is made relative to current page url, so to "10.1.1.32:8081/nullSelectStreets"

Comment: aww...makes sense! thank you so much!